# Selenium automation Python (Web Scraping)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I've developed a Python-based web scraping code using Selenium. Unfortunately, the process takes quite some time, and my Chrome webpage tends to reload automatically, causing interruptions to my scraping activities. I need a solution how to tackle this issue.

Comment: Why does it reload? Why does it take a long time? Please provide more details. For more information see [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It takes Long time Coz there is a Dropdown with Mutiple Option  After Selecting one after the Other it has Scrap the Data so it takes the Time to Go through Each Loop